# Pros/Cons of Search Icon on Search Field

Tags: search

What do you think which is the best search field solution?

[image]

And why? Is there any research on this topic? To which direction should the search icon face?

Comment: btw, os x does 2.

Comment: I think there are conflicting underlying assumptions in the answers (re 'input preceding action' in one, safari/chrome mentioned in another comment) - what you haven't specified is _is the icon a label or a button?_

Comment: @josh - When you open a blue Spotlight box (⌘+Space on my machine, but normally ^+Space I think) it's none of these. 4.) is the closest but the magnifying glass sits above the search box in the top-right corner of the desktop. BTW: I also think 4.) is the best choice here.

Comment: You should also propose a layout that includes a search *button*. I know many old people that don't know hitting enter on a text input submits the form. They always look for a button to click.

Comment: @JoJo that's if the search isn't performed when the text changes.

Comment: @Jojo the search bar will work like google instant (will search automatically when typing text) so user won't be able to click on 'search' button

Comment: I think you should A/B test it, and post the results. I will bet on 2, but testing will show you the real answer.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When the icon is on the left, it looks like a search box indicator. When it's on the right, people are more likely to think it's a submit button and try and click it. MY choice would depend on your intended function of the icon.

When I look at the icons, numbers 2 and 4 seem more natural to me, probably because they are oriented the same way as a mouse pointer. 1 and 3 just feel wrong :)

Comment: Maybe your answer will be the solution for us, because we only want to indicate with the magnifier, that it is a search bar. The icon won't be clickable, because it wouldn't make any sense in case of auto search (like google instant)

Comment: Agreed. For auto search the left hand positioning will work best.

Comment: In addition, HTML5 search fields may implement an 'x' clearing icon on the right side that would interfere with the search icon.

Comment: @Kalessin: The reason why 2 and 4 seem unnatural to you is because you are right handed.

Comment: @BaGi: Since I am in fact *left* handed, I think my answer was closer.

Comment: @Kalessin: What I meant to say is: The reason why 2 and 4 seem **more natural** to you is because you are right handed.
The fact that you found 2 and 4 more natural made me assume that you are right handed. Since you are in fact left handed it leads me to the conclusion that the orientation of the icon is possibly not related to being either left or right handed (at least not for everyone). In other words, I was probably wrong.

Answer (score 20):

Four.

Evidence from psychology indicates that people respond faster with their dominant hand to objects/lines that appear oriented towards that hand or that are positioned consistent with the location of that hand (such as on the right of the screen for a right-handed response). See [Symes, Ellis & Tucker, 2007](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001691806000412) for one example of this. There's some argument about whether this effect is because the orientation affords grasping of the object (even if it isn't actually a real 3D object), or whether it's just to do with line orientation — see also [Cho & Proctor, 2010](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0096152310600831).

Anyway, as a couple of people have pointed out, 90-odd per cent of people are right-handed, so if you want a fast motor decision (that is, if your user is likely to use the mouse, trackpad or touch interface to click inside the search box) then Four might be a good choice. However, I think One also works quite well, because its placement on the left of the search box is consistent with its orientation to be grasped/responded to with the left hand. On that basis, Two and Three are less good because they are oriented unnaturally for our hands: they only "work" (if you buy the grasping affordance argument) if your hands are actually crossed over at the wrist.

I'd also say that the angle of the search icon's handle in Two and Three tends to lead the eye out of the search box rather than towards the middle, which is not really what you want, so personally I'd avoid those. But practice and mileage obviously varies!

Answer (score 8):

I'd possibly go with 4. Simply because it looks like it could be held in the right hand; and right-handedness has a 90% dominance.

[And I've never really thought about that in a UX context before.]

Comment: This is also what OS X does (more-or-less) with the blue Spotlight search box in the top-right corner of the screen. It looks good to me.

Answer (score 5):

I like 3.

( And that's what's sitting up at the top right of my copy of Firefox right now. )

Having it on the right hand side makes it part of the left to right flow - type text then press search.

The orientation is a bit more subjective.  I suspect its just what you get used to.

Answer (score 4):

In real life the orientation of the magnifying glass depends whether you are holding it with your left or right hand.

As more people are right handed I suspect the alignment in 2 and 4 looks more natural (it does to me).

Answer (score 3):

Another factor to consider is whether you use the Clear Field Button pattern - that little (x) button that appears inside the search field which lets you clear the field quickly. That button pretty much usually only appears on the right, which might collide with the search icon.

[image: clear field button]

And then there's the possibility of search-zone selectors to further muddy the visual space.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with 3, because of all the left-to-right-flow-thing and also the 'input preceding action' thing.
And 3 instead of 4, because of all the [emotion-matrix-thing](http://www.artlebedev.com/mandership/137/) .

Comment: although, if you hold the magnifying glass in your right hand, tyhe 4th seems a bit more logical. hmm..

Answer (score 1):

Number 2 would be my choice under this circumstance.

If users are using the search tool that involve loger search strings it allows for the text to expand right with out blockage from your search icon.

The other thing that I like about number 2 is that the circle and the descending line of your icon create a nice even break that

Answer (score 0):

Three.

As Phillip mentioned, it fits the flow or eye movement better. I type my word or phrase, as an English speaker my eye goes to the right. Presto.

See this article for a nice overview of designs: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/12/04/designing-the-holy-search-box-examples-and-best-practices/

Halfway down is the brief section on magnifying glasses - their take is to do what best fits your needs. No hard and fasts. But I still like moving from left to right.

Edit: I see what people are saying about the glass in the right hand. That's nice mapping, so 4 would also work.

Comment: If the answer is always 3, why do Google and Apple use 2 in their browsers?

Comment: @ John. It's a joke, playing on the saying about multiple choice tests, "The answer is always C."

Comment: Sorry, missed the tongue in cheek!

Comment: I edited it out for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Four. The icon is positioned towards the right hand *and* the search icon (which I assume is the search/submit button here) is after the search box. Of course this would apply only to left to right reading languages.

Answer (score 0):

So, for the moment I am the only one to prefer solution 1.

Actually I do not like 2 and 3 because the orientation of the magnifying glass does not go towards the searched text.

And I do not like 4 because the icon is on the right and I am accustomed of reading from the left to the right.

Also, the shape of the field in solution 1 reminds me of a forward slash `/`, which is a shortcut in order to start a search both in Firefox or Vim, and also in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

When search icon perform an action so it will be on right side like

[image]

when search icon does not perform action but only for usability and progress loading like area51.stackexchange.com
then its should be on right side. like

[image]

[Smash magzine article for search box icon](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/12/04/designing-the-holy-search-box-examples-and-best-practices/)

Comment: it is strange that bing uses the left handed magnifier icon! We've discussed above that it feels rather unnatural...

Comment: yes but this left side icon perform action, which is good and natural

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I did a small survey with 50 people (general US population) between your option 2. and 4. to doublecheck suggestions made here.
The option with the icon on the right-side was preferred by 66% of voters compared to 34% that preferred the icon on the left side.

Keep in mind that this was a survey and not usage data.